# python can't print list from method in class

Tags: python-3.x, class

I am a new guy here and I am beginner in python. I have some code and I want to print a list of card, but instead of this my program is printing a list of object names in memory (I don't know excacly how to call that)

```
import random

class Card:
    def __init__(self, figure, colour):
        self.colour = colour
        self.figure = figure

    def show(self):
        print(self.figure + self.colour)

class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []
        self.createDeck()

    def createDeck(self):
        for colour in ["h", "d", "c", "s"]:
            for figure in ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]:
                self.deck.append(Card(figure, colour))

    def show(self):
        for card in self.deck:
            card.show()

    def showListOfCards(self):
        print(self.deck)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    deck = Deck()
    deck.createDeck()
    deck.showListOfCards()
```

Why method showListOfCards doesn't work? What should I change? Thank you for a help.

Comment: I think you meant to call `deck.show` instead of `deck.showListOfCards`

Comment: No no, deck.show is working fine, I want to print a list, not a cards one after another.

Comment: What's the result when you print this? print(self.deck)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work you can change how the `Card()` class represents itself. You do this with the builtin magic method `__repr__`. Here is an example:

```py
class Card:
    def __init__(self, figure, colour):
        self.colour = colour
        self.figure = figure

    def show(self):
        print(self.figure + self.colour)

    def __repr__(self): # How the cards appear in your list
        return str(self.figure) + str(self.colour)
```

The cards are now displayed by their figure and color, similar to how your `show` method works. What makes this different is that every element in this list is not just a string, but an actual reference to that card. In this particular case that is pretty useless, as you are only printing the list (not returning it).